# Why isn't my Teseo-LIV3FL's CEP value within the datasheet specifications?

Tags: antenna, gnss, patch-antenna

Context: **CEP** is defined as the radius of a circle, centered on the mean, whose perimeter is expected to include the landing points of 50% of the rounds (Wikipedia.)

According to the Teseo's datasheet, this module could reach 1.5m CEP with a roof antenna on a open sky location. When I tested my own module on a sunny day with open sky environment, I only got 6.12m CEP. I used an Abracon APARM1804-SG3 patch antenna.

This is how I assembled the antenna on my board:

[image]

Since I'm using a different type of antenna (the patch antenna one,) does the antenna type matter? If yes, why and how did it affect my measurement? I can't find any literature or article that explains about this.

**EDIT #1**

Here's the screenshot for the relevant section and [link to the datasheet:](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/teseo-liv3fl.pdf)

[image]

[Antenna datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.id/datasheet/2/3/APARM1804-SG3-1509139.pdf)

Comment: Your test gave you a larger value by a factor of about 4. What more do you want?

Comment: Since you are mentioning a datasheet in your question, a link to it and a screenshot of the relevant section should be included in your question. Also the info on other components of your setup should be referenced to, as well as a picture of it in action, so that we can see whether it is other components or maybe something about the way you set it up that is giving you an error outside of specified margins.

Comment: @EdinFifić Hi, I've added the link to both for the GNSS module and antenna datasheet. I don't really have a good knowledge about other components on the board since my main task is not on the hardware side, but I can provide a closer photograph to the board if needed?

Comment: @SolarMike I know my test result gave a larger value, I'm just wondering if the cause of larger value is by the antenna type difference or maybe there are other factors that could lead to large values